# Create mask for an array

Tags: python, loops, mask

I am trying to generalize a code I have that works like this:

```
rhosub=0    ##Index
mask=[]
for idx, n in enumerate(rho_ss.dims[0]):
    if idx==rhosub:
        mask.append(True)
    else:
        mask.append(False)
mask
```

Here the for loop idx goes from 0 to some value, let say 10. In this case, mask=[True, False, False, False,..., False] because I set rhosub=0.

I am trying to generalize it to multiple indices, i.e. rhosub=[0,1,3] such that mask=[True, True, False, True, False,..., False].

It may be just a trivial thing, but I have tried and failed. So if somebody could help me, I would appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `idx in rhosub` instead of `idx == rhosub`?

Comment: @gimix unbelievable, you are right! i was unaware of this. thank you